# Download public files from cloud.google.com using python when it requires login

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, urllib, pycurl

I'm trying to download the twitter misinformation/elections-integrity dataset at:
https://storage.cloud.google.com/twitter-election-integrity/hashed/ira/ira_media_file_list_hashed.txt

But it requires a login. I'm not using Google App Engine, just python 3 running on my laptop. I've written the following code to download the files:

```
for a_url in download_urls:
    filename = os.path.join(data_path, os.path.basename(a_url))

    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        #urllib.request.urlretrieve(a_url, filename)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            c = pycurl.Curl()
            c.setopt(c.URL, a_url)
            c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, f)
            c.setopt(c.CAINFO, certifi.where())
            c.perform()
            c.close()
```

### Is there a way I can download these files while avoiding having to log in to my google account?

### Or is there a easy way to login via python?

Almost all the information online is how to do this from within a GAE environment, and I'm not trying to connect to a bucket.

Comment: Can you include the error you're getting when you try to download the files?

Comment: Is there an API call to get this data instead of using pycurl on each file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL mentioned indicates that the files are served from [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/). Since logging in is required it means the objects aren't [publicly accessible](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).

The application serving these files uses a user-centric OAuth 2.0 flow. From [Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-flows):

> Cloud Storage uses [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) for API authentication and
> authorization. Authentication is the process of determining the
> identity of a client.
>
> - A user-centric flow allows an application to obtain credentials from an end user. The user signs in to complete authentication.

`Is there a way I can download these files while avoiding having to log in to my google account?`

The answer here should be **no**. Otherwise it's a bug - you'd be able to bypass Google Cloud security ;)

I couldn't find specifics for `pycurl`, but `curl` itself doesn't list OAuth 2.0 as supported. From [Features -- what can curl do](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/features.html):

> HTTP
>
> - authentication: Basic, Digest, NTLM (*9) and Negotiate (SPNEGO) (*3)    to server and proxy

So I think you won't be able to download the files using `pycurl`. At least not directly (maybe via a proxy?).

One possible alternative would be to use the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)'s [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) in your script (launched as any other external process).:

- you'd first obtain an authentication token with [`gcloud auth login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login).
- you'd then launch your script, the `gsutil` executions inside it will use the previously obtained authentication token

I see it's possible to install and use `gsutil` in standalone mode, without the cloud SDK, but I didn't use it this way. Maybe it's worth investigating for your case. From [`gsutil config`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config):

> The `gsutil config` command applies to users who have installed gsutil
> as a standalone tool.
>
> The `gsutil config` command obtains access credentials for Google
> Cloud Storage and writes a boto/gsutil configuration file containing
> the obtained credentials along with a number of other
> configuration-controllable values.